# Desctructuring data-set in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I want to extract some variables and the props like this

```
const MyComponent = (props, {data}) => {

return (
        <div data-set={props["data-set"]}>
          {data.name}
        </div>
       )
};
```

of course this doesn't work. How do I desctructure the data-set value or how do I keep props while destructuring data ??

Answer (score 0):

Because it's only one variable I want to destructure, I could just use

```
const MyComponent = props => {
 
const { data } = props   // adding this line here

return (
        <div data-set={props["data-set"]}>
          {data.name}
        </div>
       )
};
```

but if it were a bigger or more nested object, it my not be as cool

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for rest:

```
const MyComponent = (props, { data, ...rest }) => {
  return <div data-set={rest["data-set"]}>{data.name}</div>;
};
```